# Problems rendering a 3d model on a 2d gui

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, render, orthographic

I'm out of ideas as to why my model renders fine in Perspective mode, but buggy in ortho mode. The model consists of 2 cubes, one large and one small on top. In Ortho mode the small cube renders behind the large one, altough it shouldn't:

[image]

Obvisouly I'm doing something right because the large cube renders entirely correctly, even when rotated in any direction. Perhaps something related to the fact that in ortho mode the depth buffer is linear?
My znear and zfar values in orthomode are 0.4 and 1000. Depth testing is enabled. The model (= both cubes) is stored in an VAO with 3 vbos (for vertices, uvs and rgbas)

The model is rendered using this shader:

Vertex:

```
#version 330
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location: enable

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPositionIn;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvIn;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 colorIn;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

out vec2 uv;
out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    uv = uvIn;
    color = colorIn;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexPositionIn, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330

in vec2 uv;
in vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D itemTex;

void main () {
  gl_FragColor = texture(itemTex, uv) * color;
}
```

Ortho mode setup

```
public void OrthoMode(int width, int height)
{
    GlMatrixModeProjection();
    GlPushMatrix();
    GlLoadIdentity();
    GlOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0.4f, 1001);  
    LoadCurrentProjectionMatrix();

    GlMatrixModeModelView();
    GlPushMatrix();
    GlLoadIdentity();
    GlTranslate(0, 0, -500); // Translate far in the back so we can also render 3d stuff
    LoadCurrentModelViewMatrix();
}
```

Draw call:

```
[....]
game.GlPushMatrix();
    game.GlTranslate((float)posX, (float)posY, (float)posZ);
    DrawItemStack(modelref, size, rotate);
game.GlPopMatrix();
[....]

public void DrawItemStack(ModelRef modelref, float size, bool rotate = false)
{
    game.GlPushMatrix();
        game.GlTranslate(0.5f * size, 0.5f * size, 0.5f * size);

        game.GlRotate(180f + 22.6f, 1, 0, 0); // In ortho mode our y-axis is flipped
        game.GlRotate(-45.3f + (rotate ? game.CurrentTimeMilliseconds / 50f : 0), 0, 1, 0);

        game.GlScale(size * 0.5f, size * 0.5f, size * 0.5f);

        game.GlTranslate(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

        game.LoadCurrentProjectionMatrixUniform(0);
        game.LoadCurrentModelviewMatrixUniform(1);

        game.Platform.DrawModelNew(modelref); // Calls GL.DrawElements()

    game.GlPopMatrix();
}
```

And finally, he's an animated gif how it behaves when rotated:
[image]

Comment: Please add the code showing your ortho mode setup and depth setup.

Comment: added ortho mode setup (i'm doing the matrix calculations myself, so not calling native opengl matrix methods).

Depth setup is just a simple enable depth test.

Comment: Hm. Looks funny to me. Lets try something else. Get gDEBugger/CodeXL and analyze the depth of the two cubes. If equal, you have problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it seems like the small cube is literally behind the large cube. I've taken two samples of the depth buffer using gDEBugger here, the small cube has a smaller depth value:  http://imgur.com/AVwQFae


Hm this is so perplexing.

Comment: I can still paste the draw call where i apply some rotation

Comment: Perhpas it's related to how I rotate the model so that it has perspective view in the gui

Comment: Replace all magic numbers with named constants.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you manage multiple depth? How do you make sure the 2d gui is on top of the 3d world? How do stuff in the gui get "correct" depth? I myself mess around mixing 2d and 3d and find it tricky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112039/discussion-between-tyron-and-andreas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just a silly mistake - I forgot to enable depth masking -.-